# Save the states of the activity - android

Tags: android, audio

I worked on AudioProject and I want to save the states of the meadia player as example ( the position of the seek bar , the time .. and many things )

How can I save the states of the activity because I want to use it when I resume the activity

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Saving_and_Restoring_the_User_Interface_State_of_an_Android_Activity

Try out this tutorial page and follow their code! :)